# EPERM: operation not permitted

Tags: node.js

Я хочу переместить файлы из одной папки в другую, но выдает эту ошибку EPERM: operation not permitted

```
const path1800=path.join(__dirname,'1800');
const dir=path.join(__dirname,'1999');
    fs.readdir(dir,(err, files) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        files.forEach(value => {
            fs.readdir(path1800,(err1,file1) => {
                file1.forEach(value2=>{
                    fs.rename(`${dir}/${value}`,`${path1800}/${value2}`,err2 => {
                        if(err2){
                            console.log(err2);
                        }
                    })
                })
            })
        })
    })
```

Comment: Что-то я не понял зачем тут второй цикл по path1800

Comment: А как нужно заменять файл на файл или нет?

Comment: а [такой](https://pastebin.com/utWuw2UA) код даёт ошибку?

Comment: такой хорошо работает

Comment: и этот код выполняет стоящую перед вами задачу?